# Table properties which have been set appear undefined

Tags: javascript, properties, titanium

I am pushing the following items to an array:

```
data.push({
            title: items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).text,
            leftImage: "News Story.png",
            dataToPass: items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("content:encoded").item(0).text,

            className: "TableRow", 
            hasChild: true, 
            js:"external.js"
        });
```

I am setting this array to be the data source of a table.

```
table.data = data;
```

This works fine and the table is displayed as desire. However,I then have an event listener, on when a row of a table is clicked. In that I have a condition testing if it has a js property and if it has a dataToPass property and this is returning false, can anyone explain this?

```
table.addEventListener("click", function (e){

if(e.source.title){
            alert("has title");
        }

if (e.source.dataToPass){
            alert ("got data");
        }
if (e.source.js){
            alert("has js");
        }
```

I am receiving the alert for has title but not, got data. Why?

Comment: Are you sure the table data maps directly to properties on the DOM element? Is `e.source` even the correct DOM element? There's not really enough information here for anyone to help.

Comment: @jbabey if am printing e.source.title and it's printing the desired output so the 'e' part isn't the problem. Should I include the entire js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create table rows from JSON objects, you have to access the data from the `rowData` object, try this:

```
table.addEventListener("click", function (e){
    if(e.source.title){
            alert("has title");
    }

    if (e.rowData.dataToPass){
            alert ("got data");
    }
});
```

This is documented more throuroughly in the [API.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableViewRow-event-click)

Comment: thanks a million! I still don't really understand why it works for some of the elements but not them all but sincere thanks for fixing it

Comment: Some would call this a bug, if you add rows to a table piece meal, then you have to access the data either through e.source or e.row, but when you create it with a JSON object like you did, you must use e.rowData.

Comment: Hi Josiah I am pushing items to a data array and then adding these to a rowData array in order to create custom rows for a table. This is working fine. I now need to know how to access these when a user clicks a specific row. I was previously using your solution i.e. e.rowData.title etc. for accessing these elements when I had a basic table but now that it is a custom table, this isn't working. e.row and e.source aren't working :/ see eited code above if you have a spare minute please!!!

Comment: Can you move this to a new question please? This could confuse future readers If I answer both here.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727510/accessing-elements-of-a-custom-table/17727634?noredirect=1#17727634